# do not want to print comma in the end

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am iterating through an array which should be displayed in this manner:

```
    k,j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a,
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
b,b,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,
z,y,x,w,v,u,t,s,r,q,p,
```

but without an comma in the end. This is what i am doing so far.

```
for ( int k = 0;  k < lineChar.length;  k++ ) //for printing in reverse order
            {
                if(lineChar[n] != ','){

                System.out.print(lineChar[n]);
                if(k == lineChar.length-1)
                   System.out.print("");
                else
                   System.out.print(",");

                --n;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: I find it easiest to use a StringBuffer to build up the string I'm eventually going to print, putting a comma before _every_ item (even the first), and then at the end, after the loop completes, use one `.print()` statement to print the whole StringBuffer starting from its second character. That way I don't need any `if/else` structures or other tests inside the loop. By the way, you don't need to print an empty string in your current `if` branch.

Comment: Would you be okay using a 3rd party library?  Or are you wanting to write the code that does this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n=lineChar.lenght-1;

//Next 2 lines are edit after comment by @aix
while ((lineChar[n]==',') && (n>=0)) n--;
if (n>=0) System.out.print(lineChar[n--]);

for (;  n >=0;  n-- ) {
  if(lineChar[n] != ',') {
    System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(lineChar[n]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if `lineChar[lineChar.length-1]==','`? The OP's code wouldn't print it out, and your code would.

Comment: What if the first character is a ","?

Comment: @Adam If the first character is a ",", it is not printed, being last in the loop, so the `if(lineChar[n] != ',')`applies. If the last character is a "," my edits after @aix feedback will catch it

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's efficient since it only prints once at the end, uses`StringBuilder` for building the string, doesn't check for any condition inside the loop, and doesn't require any external library:

```
public static void printChar(char[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0)
        return;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(array[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
        sb.append(',').append(array[i]);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: I like this one the best, but I would make one change. Remove the call to `toString` from the last line since `println` will call the `toString` method of an object anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Guava's Joiner class as well:  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html

Your example reduces to the following:

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(',').join(lineChar));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int n = lineChar.length - 1; n >= 0; --n) {
   if (lineChar[n] != ',') {
      if (sb.length() > 0) {
         sb.append(',');
      }
      sb.append(lineChar[n]);
   }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I am assuming the `if (lineChar[n] != ',')` is there to prevent the printing of any commas that might be part of the array. If it's there for some other reason, please explain its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a delimiter variable with an initial empty value. Then I print the delimiter in front of every element and after that I assign the real delimiter token:

```
String delimiter = "";
for( int i=0; i<lineChar.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.print( delimiter );
    System.out.print( lineChar[ i ] );
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

This way I have no conditional and only one overhead assignment in each round.

This only describes the way to have no ',' at the end of your output. But you can easily adapt your other conditions (reverse iteration, skipping of special values).

Comment: will print all comma's in the array which it looks like he doesn't want to do (since he's checking before printing)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing this for school or anything that you are limited in how you accomplish you could try something where you push the items into an array and then iterate through to print out (using a for loop, join statement or string builder):

```
  var result = new Array()
  for (x = 0; x < lineChar.length; x++) {
    if (lineChar[x] != ',')
      result.push(lineChar[x]);
  }
  System.out.print(result.join(","));
  System.out.println();
```

or... even simpler:

```
  var result = lineChar.split(",");
  System.out.print(result.join(",");
  System.out.println();
```

Edited to remove my third option as there are other, more accurate ones listed.

NOTE: I'm a c# and jscript programmer so syntax may be a little off for java, but I went with jscript thinking it would be similar.

Comment: OP's question has the `java` tag, this answer won't work in Java. Regardless of the note at the end, you should stick to what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

why don't u simply sub string the last character after you append the , fully.

For example

> String text="a,b,c,d,e,f,";
>
> String finalText = text.substring(0,text.length()-1);